# Workday - Setup OAuth Client

Tags: workday-api

I am trying to use the workday rest api - specifically the api to get inbox tasks - https://doc.workday.com/reader/wsiU0cnNjCc_k7shLNxLEA/STuD3Gmw7K_DGCyaB…

I want to set it up to use OAuth for authentication

I followed this link to start setting up OAuth - https://doc.workday.com/reader/wsiU0cnNjCc_k7shLNxLEA/JfMMxf0x4NmfBKVT~…

However I dont have any documentation on what to pass in the api call for the request data

Has anyone done this previously or can you send on the expected request and response data for the token call?

Thank you
Damien

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been directed to the workday link for OAuth

All details can be found here
https://community.workday.com/rest/oauth

Comment: This is a private url